# Why couldn't my very specific page appear on Google search results even when I put my site name beside the search terms?

Tags: seo, wordpress, keywords

I made an article on "nexgrill vs char broil". I used keywords, I optimized, improved my readability, but still, when I search "nexgrill vs char broil", I see only 2 or 3 websites (on the first page of search results) whose article is purely on "Nexgrill vs Char Broil". The following results were all either forum posts or other grill topics.

I even tried searching "nexgrill vs char broil + sitename" but even though results showed my website on the top results, the articles were still not my "Nexgrill vs Char broil" article. Shown articles were other grill related articles, such as "Best xxxx"

I already tried decreasing keyword density, comparing my article to the top search result articles, using the same words they used, such as "compare", "best", "comparison", "2020", etc.

I'm hopeless! What could I do? I'm in big trouble if I don't make a way, someone will be mad. Please help me, and thank you!

Comment: Is the particular page indexed at all? If you were to search: `site:example.com intitle:"nexgrill vs char broil"` would the page itself appear in the SERP?

Comment: Yes it does appear, but the recent changes I've made to the meta description and title still didn't show up. Thanks for this info

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you to follow the steps from the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7474347?hl=en).

You can also ask Google [to recrawl your page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812).

It usually takes time (more than 5 days) for Google to crawl, reconsider your page and update search results.